# Zenject pass monobehaviur object to factory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject

I have a Monobehaviour object BaseUnit which can have some states, so I created 
states factory, like in the Zenject example projects, but my question is how to pass reference of this BaseUnit when I create this factory of states for this BaseUnit?

```
public class UnitStateFactory
{
readonly UnitMoveState.Factory _moveState;
readonly UnitActiveState.Factory _activeState;
readonly BaseUnit _unit;

public UnitStateFactory(
     UnitMoveState.Factory mS,
     UnitActiveState.Factory aS,
     BaseUnit unit

     )
{

    _moveState = mS;
    _activeState = aS;
    _unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of BaseUnit? And how do you create them (do you use Zenject for creationg)?

Comment: Yes I have multiple instances of BaseUnit. All of them are created manually in the editor with Zenject binding script attached to them.

Comment: According to DI practices you'd better make each BaseUnit have it's own factory (or share instance), so you have to inject the factory to unit

Comment: Yes i'm doing this, injecting state factory in the unit, but then at some point state needs to know position of the unit and I don't how to pass this information appropriately is using DI.

Comment: If you have BaseUnit which has a factory as a dependancy and you want to pass BaseUnit to factory as dependancy - it's circular dependancy, which cannot be done in any DI container. it's a bad architecture approach. But you can do it if you add smth like Init method to factory and make unit pass it self in this Init method

Comment: I will think some more how to avoid this, thank you for your help

Comment: I agree that circular dependencies are a sign of a bad design, but you can do them in zenject.  You just can't do them with constructor injection - you have to use property / field / method injection instead.

In cases like this, where you have a set of classes that you want to work together, you might consider using a subcontainer.  Then within each subcontainer there would be an instance of BaseUnit, and a state factory, etc. and they could all treat each other as if they were singletons without a problem.